# JBoss AS 7 Log4j in webapplication not change log level

Tags: spring, logging, jboss, log4j, jboss7.x

Here is content of files

classes/log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%c] - <%m>%n

# Enable web flow logging
log4j.category.org.springframework.webflow=DEBUG
log4j.category.org.springframework.faces=DEBUG
log4j.category.org.springframework.binding=DEBUG
log4j.category.org.springframework.transaction=DEBUG
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
       <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
   <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
   <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

For each dependency which contain commons-logging, SLF4j is make exclusion.

WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>        
        <exclusions>
             <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

When I start server in eclipse on console I still see only INFO log and WARN. I need DEBUG logging spring framework. What's is wrong with this configuration??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing much clear about it. Seems like a bug with AS7

To have app specific logging level you need to

> configure in your app in WEB-INF/classes/logging.properties or log4j.properties or log4j.xml

refer ondrej ziska comment at [AS7-514](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-514) for detailed info

Comment: On jboss 7.1.1 Final this solution not work. Tomorrow I try it on 7.1.0 and 7.1.2 version of jboss which is in middleware blog post mentioned by ondrej ziska in his post.

Comment: @BartekM a piece of advice. Use AS7 nightly builds , judt click on the last successful artifact here : https://ci.jboss.org/jenkins/job/JBoss-AS-7.x-latest/   , AS7.1.1 that was released is continously going a lot of bug fixes. So its advisable.

Comment: thanks for advice. I downloaded latest version - jboss-as-7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT from Jenkins, then I encountered problem with hibernate. In this moment I run my application on jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final and ther logging in application work correctly.

Comment: Great so logging resolved. What sort of hibernate issue? i suppose it should be some configuration mismatch.

Comment: When I config onlyn log4j in application it's looks like logging is off. On console is throws only a few logs from JBoss with INFO Level. So I add META-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml with structure like in question to get conf in application and then I get `log4j:ERROR A "org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender" object is not assignable to a "org.apache.log4j.Appender" variable` and `log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "stdout"`, when persistence.xml is readed. So I find this could be caused  by double lib of lof4j. Everywhere I have only one lib and module is excluded from deploy.

Comment: @BartekM , log4j is the default logger for JBoss. so 1) you dont need its jars in your application (unless there are some version specifications) 2) just use `log4j` in your application, you dont need to place any jars, or configure in jboss-deployment-structure.xml. 
3) or you could be looking for something like [this](https://community.jboss.org/thread/195061)

Answer (score 1):

From the JBoss wiki page on configuring your application using log4j at https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/How+To:

I see in step 2, Include the log4j.properties or log4j.xml file in the lib/ directory in your deployment.

You had your log4j.properties in classes/ directory. Either your log4j properties is not correctly picked up(configuration  error)or the documentation is incorrect.

If it does not work from the lib/ directory, the jboss documentation needs to be fixed.

Comment: lib/log4j.properties don't work, Looks like jboss documentation should be fixed

Answer (score 0):

The configuration is included in the logging subsystem of the AS7, e.g. in the domain.xml or standalone.xml depending of the profile and mode.

You need to add a log category for org.spring and increase the log level threshold of the console handler.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">
  <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
    <level name="DEBUG"/>
    ...    
  </console-handler>

  ...

  <logger category="org.spring">
    <level name="DEBUG"/>
  </logger>

  ...
</subsystem>
```

Comment: I know about definition logginig in standalone.xml, ther is also logginig.properties which is used when logginig subsytem is not defined in standalone.xml (asuming that I am using standalone jboss config). But problem is when I want configure logginig on the deployed application. I use jboss-deployment-structure.xml include in WEB-INF, task of this file is excluding jboss modules. I find today the default logginig module on jboss is org.jboss.as.logging, but when I add it in exclusion nothing happens.